# Django filter objects from many to many relationship

Tags: python, django, orm

I'm having a problem when trying to filter over a many-to-many relationship.

This is my models.py:

```
class Member(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Talk(models.Model):
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Member)
```

I want to get the conversations in which two members are participating.

Here are the data I have:

```
{
    "pk": 2,
    "members": [
        36384,
        12626,
        48397
    ],
},
{
    "pk": 3,
    "members": [
        36384,
        12626,
        -89813,
        48397
    ],
}
```

I want to get conversations where the two specified members participate. My query was as follows:

```
Talk.objects.filter(members__in=[12626, -89813])
```

The result I get is the following:

```
<QuerySet [<Talk: 2>, <Talk: 3>, <Talk: 3>]>
```

How can I make the result to be this?

```
<Talk: 3>
```

Note: It is in the only conversation in which the specified members are participating

Thanks

Comment: "How can I make the result to be this? `<Talk: 3>`" For that you have to change your filter query: `Talk.objects.filter(members_in=[-89813])`.

Answer (score 2):

try below django query:

```
from django.db.models import Q

Talk.objects.filter(
    Q(members__id=12626) & Q(members__id=-89813)
)
```

Comment: always ready to help, if found helpful please upvote and accept as the correct answer.